# Existing sheep riding a new sheep

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a sheep ride another sheep. The first sheep already exists, and I would like to make him ride a new sheep. Is there a way to do this with command blocks?

Comment: `/entitydata @e[type=Sheep] {Riding:{type:Sheep}}` - I'll post it as an answer when I can get onto a desktop.

Comment: @aytimothy I thought there would be a `summon` in there somewhere..? Could be wrong

Comment: Nope. You don't need to summon a new sheep to make it ride another. @Ben.

Comment: `/summon` is for making new entities. Since two (or more) entities riding each other is considered as a single entity, you don't need to `/summon`. You only use it if the two sheep(s) are separate..

Comment: EDIT: You don't need to summon a new mob to stack it onto another, since you're adding it straight onto the existing mob, though they're still two different entities.

Answer (score 4):

You can make a sheep riding another sheep by using the `{Riding:{[Insert Mob Info]}` NBT data.

If you want to simply add a sheep onto another, you can use:

```
/entitydata @e[type=Sheep] {Riding:{id:Sheep}}
```

> The `/entitydata` command allows you to set the NBT data within a mob.
> Its syntax is: `/entitydata [entity] [new data]`

---

However, this does not work as stacked entities are considered two different entities, though it is the correct command.

#### Why?

When you use `/summon` with the `{Riding:{id:[Mob Name]}}` NBT data, the game automatically creates the mob for you. (All the other data, from UUID to statuses).

However, using the `/entitydata` command only appends on the NBT data you've added. So, adding on `{Riding:{id:[MobName]}}` isn't simply enough to define a mob.

**Update:** You can't apprehend an entity onto another entity without manually editing its entity. (Safeguard or bug).

#### Suggested way to do it:

1. Open your `.mca` world data with any NBT Editor such as [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac)
2. Look for the location of the two mobs you want to merge.
   *Use F3 to look for the chunk co-ordinates you're in. Don't use the raw co-ordinates.*
3. Go to the chunk(s) that the mobs are in with your NBT Editor.
4. Go to the entity you want to be at the top of the stack.
   *Entities are found in `Chunk [X, Y] > Level > Entities > ...`*
5. Create a compound tag within the entity's compound tag. Name it `Riding:`
   *The colon has to be there. Capitalization also matters.*
6. Go to the entity that you want to be at the bottom of the stack.
7. Cut all the entries within the entity's compound tag and move it into the newly created `Riding:` compound tag you've created.
8. Now, delete the old entity's compound tag. (To clean up)
9. Save and open in Minecraft. Go to the location of the mob you *haven't* deleted.

If you want stacks bigger than 2, it gets more complicated.

Comment: This isn't working. For some reason, adding the tag later is not changing anything. Maybe this is a bug?

Comment: Just revised my answer. The command didn't work because the mob type identifier is `{id:[Mob Type]}` and adding 1 to the score of nearby sheeps would simply mess up the `isNear=1` condition I'm looking for. (It means: The condition would be true for only a tick before it continues to count up wildly)

Comment: The first solution didn't work either though.

Comment: @kittycat3141 Are you using 1.8? Are you using the correct capitals? `@e[type=zombie]` is wrong and different to `@e[type=Zombie]`.

Comment: Yes, I checked both.

Comment: Did you type the command correctly? Are you using 1.8?

Comment: I think so, I tried several times.

Comment: Hm.. The command follows the books, but it's not working (I've tested it). I suspect it may be a "safeguard" (if any) of some sort. I guess that the only way to do so is to edit the mob data.

Comment: Could also be a bug.

Comment: Actually, continue this in chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19631/discussion-between-aytimothy-and-kittycat3141).