# New sheep riding an existing sheep

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This is similar to [another question I posted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/197100/existing-sheep-riding-a-new-sheep), but in reverse. Can I spawn a sheep (or any other entity) to ride another, existing entity, like a player or another sheep?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Existing sheep riding a new sheep](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/197100/existing-sheep-riding-a-new-sheep)

Comment: You don't really need a separate question for this.

Comment: @Frank It is a different question. The answers will be quite different because of the way Minecraft commands work.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the UUID of the existing entity, you might be able to do something like:

```
/summon Sheep ~ ~ ~ {Riding:{id:"Sheep",UUID:<entity-uuid>}}
```

However, I don't know how to get the UUID of a mob, nor do I know if this command will use the existing entity or duplicate it. Summoning mobs with a specific UUID could be weird.